# Amazon Signature version 2 Expires header missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-headers

I'm trying to authenticate a request using signature version 2. When I send the request to perform a GetObject action I get an error response asking for an expires header.

According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-2.html this should not be a problem.

**Is aws trying to authenticate using sigv4 or is this perhaps a s3 GetObject specific problem?**

*In case there is interest in the response:*

```
- <Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
  - <Message>
      Query-string authentication requires the Signature, Expires and AWSAccessKeyId parameters
    </Message>
    <RequestId>...</RequestId>
  - <HostId>
      ...
    </HostId>
  </Error>
```

Comment: It does not say that there should not be a problem :) As mentioned in the document, many regions do not support SigV2. Which endpoint you are making the request to and could you share the exact error please?

Comment: endpoint: s3.amazonaws.com, this shouldn't be the problem. I appreciate the response! :)

Comment: Please provide the *exact* error, and show us what your signed URL looks like.